# Do marriages still apply across faiths in Westeros?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133278/would-this-character-still-be-a-bastard) about Jon's bastard status, it occurred to me that people in the south get married in a sept, whereas people in the north generally get married before a Weirwood tree.

This raised the question about whether people following different religions, and having different marriage ceremonies, still believe they are married in the eyes of foreign gods?

Further to this, there are other religions outside of Westeros, such as the Dothraki horse religion, and the religion of Rh'llor, with their own wedding customs and religious beliefs. When Daenerys married Khal Drogo, King Robert felt it was serious enough to pose a threat if they had a child, therefore people of different religions recognized the *validity* of marriages in other religions, and hence any of their offspring would have been trueborn.

But is there any precedence for someone being married, changing religion, and getting remarried as they felt their marriage was no longer legitimate within their new faith?

Comment: I assume it is the same as in our world. We have many religious and secular people who marry around the world and these marriages seem valid everywhere. And in religious circles remarrying in the new religion isn't unheard of. Though as far as I know in my country, Switzerland, only the secular marriage is binding and the marriage in the church is just for "show". Mostly this happens on the same day or for example on Friday secular and in the church on Saturday.

Comment: Catelyn and Ned are a good example of two people marrying with different religions. Catelyn was devoted to the Seven and Ned to the Old Gods

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Planetos in general is a multi-faith and multi-cultural one, just like the real world. However, In Westeros at least, It is normal for people of different faith to marry and their offspring are considered true born because Westeros has a lot of cultures and religions in one state (After Braavos maybe). I suppose it must be even more common in Essos seeing how many religions and cultures exist there even inside one city state e.g. Braavos.

Following are some Examples of Cross-faith marriages in Westeros:

1. **Queen [Lelia Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lelia_Lannister) and King [Harmund II Hoare](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harmund_II_Hoare)**: Princess Lelia Of the Rock married ward of her father, then Crown-prince of Iron Islands Prince Harmund Hoare. Harmund succeeded to Iron Throne eventually as Harmund II. Their offspring was considered true born even though they were brought up in Faith of the Seven instead of faith of the Drowned God. Her Son, Also named Harmund, Took the Throne of Iron Isles as [Harmund III Hoare](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harmund_III_Hoare) on his father's death.
2. **Lord [Eddard Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Eddard_Stark) and Lady [Catelyn Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Catelyn_Stark)**: Catelyn Tully was brought up in light of the Seven while Eddard worshipped the Old Gods. Eddard and Catelyn were married according to traditions of the faith of Seven in Sept of Riverrun.

   From AGOT Chapter 6:

   > Catelyn pulled the furs to her chin and watched him.He looked somehow
   >   smaller and more vulnerable, **like the youth she had wed in the sept
   >   at Riverrun**, fifteen long years gone.

   Their children were trueborn.
3. **Prince [Doran Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Doran_Martell) and Lady [Mellario of Norvos](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mellario)**: Not much info is available on their marriage but we know Mellario was Norvoshi and thus most likely followed the religion of bearded priests. They were however married in Dorne so it is probable that they must have been married in Faith of Seven's ways. They had three children, all of whom were trueborn in eyes of whole realm.

This concludes our few examples to establish the fact of legitimacy of children born to parents of different faith.

Now as to did someone ever change religion and felt the need to remarry, **I am afraid there is no such precedence**. Only people that we do know who changed religion (Other than the Brotherhood without Banners) are **Selyse Florent** (Devout) and **Stannis Baratheon** (Just did it for magical powers). **They did not remarry in light of R'hllor**. (<s>Though I don't know why do I keep getting the feeling that Selyse expressed that wish? I can't find any reference to prove her expression of such wish.</s> She did in ADWD when discussing Alys Karstark's wedding to Magnar of Thenn.)

People of Westeros appear to believe all the marriages as legally binding, no matter in which god's name were they performed. We have seen Weddings between followers of different faiths, performed in the way of the Seven (Eddard and Catelyn), Weddings performed in the light of Rhllor (Alys Karstark and Magnar of Thenn), Weddings performed in the old ways (Lady Hornwood and Ramsay Bolton - Hornwood was born a Manderly who follow the Seven) and all were considered legal. In Essos however, we know that at least the Ghiscari insist that weddings must be performed in ways of the gods of Ghis like how Daenerys was informed that she must wed Hizdhar zo Loraq according to Ghiscari rites or she'll be considered his concubine not legal wife, their children shall be bastards.

Comment: Also, somewhat related: most people swear "by the Old Gods and the New" in Westeros, showing that they're both accepted.